# Не работает isChecked()

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты, qradiobutton

Не вызывается `isCheked()` на радиобаттоны.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(332, 337)
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton()
        self.radioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.buttonGroup = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(Dialog)
        self.buttonGroup.setObjectName("buttonGroup")
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.radioButton)
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(Dialog)
        self.radioButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 30, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.radioButton_2)
        self.radioButton_3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(Dialog)
        self.radioButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 30, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton_3.setObjectName("radioButton_3")
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.radioButton_3)
        self.radioButton_4 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(Dialog)
        self.radioButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton_4.setObjectName("radioButton_4")
        self.buttonGroup_2 = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(Dialog)
        self.buttonGroup_2.setObjectName("buttonGroup_2")
        self.buttonGroup_2.addButton(self.radioButton_4)
        self.radioButton_5 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(Dialog)
        self.radioButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 60, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton_5.setObjectName("radioButton_5")
        self.buttonGroup_2.addButton(self.radioButton_5)
        self.radioButton_6 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(Dialog)
        self.radioButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 60, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton_6.setObjectName("radioButton_6")
        self.buttonGroup_2.addButton(self.radioButton_6)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 210, 47, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 200, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.add_functions()
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "2"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "3"))
        self.radioButton_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "5"))
        self.radioButton_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "1"))
        self.radioButton_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "4"))
        self.radioButton_6.setText(_translate("Dialog", "6"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "TextLabel"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PushButton"))

    def add_functions(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        

    def clicked(self):
        radioBtn  = Dialog.sender()
        if radioBtn.isChecked():
            # ???
            pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: `radioBtn.isCheked`?

Comment: Пишет ошибку при таком выборе   if radioBtn.ischeked
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: В isCheked пропущено c перед k, должно быть isChecked

Comment: Без разницы, в любом случае ошибку пишет

Comment: Тогда укажите какую конкретно ошибку пишет. Вообще, к clicked у вас неправильные отступы, в строке if в конце должно быть двоеточие, и у if должно быть тело (блок, который должен выполниться, если условие истинно).

Comment: if radioBtn.isChecked():
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: @insolor если можете, покажите пожалуйста как правильно сделать проверку ischecked чтобы она работала

Comment: Ну в ошибке и написано, что у if лишний отступ, он должен быть на том же уровне отступа, как и строка выше него. Там не понятно, что конкретно должно произойти, если isChecked выполняется, поэтому не смогу написать, как должно быть правильно.

Comment: @insolor Нужно чтобы текстовые значения Radiobuttons IsChecked складывались и выводились в переменную, ну а переменную можно на экран. Суть в том что мне нужно сложить все RadioButton которые есть в GroupBox не делая проверку If self.radioButton.isChecked() на каждую radiobutton(их там будет около 80), а чтобы была сумма  только тех, что выбраны

Comment: А что же код то обрывается, даже двоеточия нет в конце строки с `if`, как-то странно.

Comment: @CrazyElf Суть не в этом, доступ к методу недоступен изначально только почему я не понимаю. Когда я пишу radioBtn. то метода isChecked не появляется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ** код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, **НИКОГДА**. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(332, 337)
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton()
        self.radioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.buttonGroup = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(Dialog)
        self.buttonGroup.setObjectName("buttonGroup")
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.radioButton)
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(Dialog)
        self.radioButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 30, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.radioButton_2)
        self.radioButton_3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(Dialog)
        self.radioButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 30, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton_3.setObjectName("radioButton_3")
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.radioButton_3)
        self.radioButton_4 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(Dialog)
        self.radioButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton_4.setObjectName("radioButton_4")
        self.buttonGroup_2 = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(Dialog)
        self.buttonGroup_2.setObjectName("buttonGroup_2")
        self.buttonGroup_2.addButton(self.radioButton_4)
        self.radioButton_5 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(Dialog)
        self.radioButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 60, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton_5.setObjectName("radioButton_5")
        self.buttonGroup_2.addButton(self.radioButton_5)
        self.radioButton_6 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(Dialog)
        self.radioButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 60, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton_6.setObjectName("radioButton_6")
        self.buttonGroup_2.addButton(self.radioButton_6)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 210, 47, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 200, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "2"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "3"))
        self.radioButton_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "5"))
        self.radioButton_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "1"))
        self.radioButton_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "4"))
        self.radioButton_6.setText(_translate("Dialog", "6"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "TextLabel"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PushButton"))


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        
        self.radioButtons = self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QRadioButton)

    def clicked(self):
        for rb in self.radioButtons:
            if rb.isChecked():
                print(f'{rb.text()} --> {rb.isChecked()}') #
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, спасибо большое оно. А как обнулить это значение? Например если добавить comboBox и при выборе другого значения обнулять эту таблицу радиобаттонов?